# Excel VBA TreeView Looping Through Child Nodes

Tags: excel, treeview, vba

I am using Excel TreeView object. I have no problem looping through Parent nodes, but can't get it to work with child nodes.

Here's how I am doing it with the parent nodes. This works fine.

```
Total_Rows =10
For I = 1 To (Total_Row - 2) 'subtract two for the headers
    If TreeView1.Nodes(I).Checked = True Then
        Range("Nodes_Checked")(I + 2) = "x"
    End If
Next I
```

Here is how I was doing it with child nodes. This appears to only check the first child node, not all nodes.

```
For i = 1 To (2) 'subtract two for the headers
   If TreeView1.Nodes(i).Child.Checked = True Then
      MsgBox "The child node is checked"
   End If
Next i
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/76624464/4932683