# Loop through treeview parent and child nodes

Tags: excel, vba

I have a treeview control with three parent nodes each containing three child nodes.

```
Parent1
   Child11
   Child12
   Child13
Parent2
   Child21
   Child22
   Child23
Parent3
   Child31
   Child32
   Child33
```

How do I loop through each parent node to check whether its child nodes are checked?

Something like

```
For Each n In Parent1.Nodes
    If n.checked Then
        ............
    End If
Next n
```

Comment: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?76151-Loop-through-Treeview-Node%27s-children&p=455637&viewfull=1#post455637

Comment: Thank u.. is there a way to use for..each iteration?

Comment: Note that the *standard `Treeview` control, like all non built-in ActiveX controls, cannot be used in 64 bit versions of Office.* - Fyi A freely editable vba alternative can be found at [MSForms (all VBA) treeview for Access, Excel And Word](https://jkp-ads.com/Articles/treeview.asp) @user3286479

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim tv As MSComctlLib.TreeView
Dim noddy As MSComctlLib.Node
Dim ctr As Integer

' tvSelectPR is the name of the treeview control on the form
Set tv = Me.tvSelectPR.Object
For ctr = 1 To tv.Nodes.count
    Set noddy = tv.Nodes.Item(ctr)
    'iterates through each node (and sub-node) in the tree
    Debug.Print noddy.key
Next
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive function to iterate through all of the node´s siblings and children.

```
'Iterates through the node's children and all of it´s next siblings
Private Sub TreeView_SiblingsAndChildren_Check(node As node)
    Do
        If node Is Nothing Then Exit Do
        
        'Do what you gotta do here
        If node.Checked Then
            '...
        End If
        
        'Do this same function to the first child node (if exists)
        If node.Children > 0 Then TreeView_SiblingsAndChildren_Check node.child
        Set node = node.Next 'Next sibling
    Loop
End Sub
```

Then to call it you use Node.child to loop through any node, or MyTreeView.Nodes(1) to loop through the whole TreeView:

```
TreeView_SiblingsAndChildren_Check MyTreeView.Nodes(1)
```